# How exactly is this string being reversed?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For quite a while now, I have been studying the following algorithm as a way to solve reverse string:

```
function reverse(str) {
    let reversed = '';
  for (let character of str) {
    reversed = character + reversed;
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

But I just realized, I am not sure exactly how, meaning the mechanics, if you will, of how the string is being reversed just by `character + reversed;`.

I know I am creating this temporary variable that is redeclared every single time through this loop of `character`, then I say `of` and the iterable object, that being `str`, one by one and set it equal to the temporary variable of `character`, then I take that `character` and add it on to the string of `reversed`.

How exactly is that reversing the string? I know if I do `reversed = reversed + character;` it will just give me the string unreversed, but whats causing it to reverse exactly? A diagram would probably be helpful.

Comment: _"then I take that `character` and add it on to the string of `reversed`"_  your confusion starts here. You are taking that `character` and adding the string of `reversed` on to it

Comment: "*I know I am creating this temporary variable that is redeclared every single time through this loop*" - No, it isn't. Assigning to a variable doesn't redeclare it.

Comment: Add some debug-output and see what happens during execution of the loop. That should make clear how this works. Debugging is your frind ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = 'abc';
reverse = '';

// iteration
reverse = 'a' + '';   // a
reverse = 'b' + 'a';  // ba
reverse = 'c' + 'ba'; // cba
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a test run with a simple [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). Eventually, you should teach yourself to use the debugger which has many more capabilities than just printing values to the screen.

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversed = '';
  for (let character of str) {
    console.log(`'${character + reversed}' = '${character}' + '${reversed}'`);
    reversed = character + reversed;
  }
  return reversed;
}

reverse('world');
```

Comment: So `console.log()` can be used for more than just accessing properties on certain objects or viewing what data will be returned to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the for loop is iterating over each character in the string. Each time it goes through the loop, it is setting the current character equal to 'character', which it then pasted in front of all the previously processed characters.

If you want to really understand what it is doing try running this:

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let reversed = '';
    for (let character of str) {
        console.info("current character being processed: " + character);
        console.info("reversed string before paste: " + reversed);
        reversed = character + reversed;
        console.info("reversed string after paste: " + reversed);
    }
    return reversed;
}

console.log('reverse("abcd") = ' + reverse("abcd"));
```

I suggest you go read up on console.log(), console.info(), console.warn(), etc. They are very helpful to use while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "ABC,DEFG,H";
console.log(str);
var reversestr = "";
for(x in str){
    console.log('reversestr = '+ str[x] + "+" + reversestr);
    reversestr = str[x] + reversestr; 
}
console.log(reversestr);
```